# Adding a 'search tips' link next to the search button in a views-based search

Tags: views

I'm using a Drupal 7 views-based search. I have a search button in there of course. I'd like to add a link next to it called 'search tips' that goes to a 'basic page'. Anyone know how to add a link there?

This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php

  /*
    * Implementation of hook_form_alter()
    */
  function search_tips_link_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == "views_exposed_form") {
    // there's a submit button in here I'd like to add a link after that...
    // not sure how to place a link with this function.
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Find the specific view exposed form by using the **#id** array key.
2. Find for the search button array key.
3. Use the [#suffix](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#suffix) form key to append your link.

A helpful tool to look into the array structure is by using the dsm() function from [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module.

Additional information for best practice is that use the [l()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) function to structure your link.

So it would look something like:

```
if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-test-page') {
  $form['submit']['#suffix'] = l(t('Search tips'), 'link-to-basic-page');
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! Drupal really is totally customizable.

Comment: Yes it is! That's what makes it awesome! :) You're very welcome! Glad you solved your issue!